# Magento: Get collection from custom query

Tags: magento

We can write a custom query in Magento:

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$write->query("insert into tablename values ('aaa','bbb','ccc')");
```

Now how can I get the output of query into a collection as I get from `Mage::getModel()->getCollection` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object that extends one of the base collection objects, and add your query to the load method.

Comment: `load()` is wrong place, `_beforeLoad()` should be used instead.

Comment: @Zyana you'd use _beforeLoad to add additional information to an existing collection you were extending.

Comment: No, you are wrong here. You need override load() method in very rare cases when you need customize logic in `Varien_Data_Collection_Db::load()`. In all other cases `_beforeLoad()`, `_renderFiltersBefore()`, etc. methods should be overloaded in child classes with custom logic. At least it is considered as best practice in magento.

Comment: I was (implicitly) suggesting <code>Varien_Data_Collection</code> as the base class and populate the collection yourself.   If you were going to use <code>Varien_Data_Collection_Db</code> you want to concentrate and getting your select into the _select property.  The real problem here is there isn't any best practices fro Magento, it's all community conjecture.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. About best practices - sure community developers may not follow any rules. But magento company employees have some set of rules and best practices and in most cases they follow them while writing new code. Of course a lot of old code still is a mess :( But things will be changed in magento2.

Comment: @Zyava There's lots of community developers who follow rules, but they're rules of their own making. Publishing the rules you mentioned would be a huge win for developer relations.